# python error could not convert string to float

Tags: python, slack

We are getting this below error while migrating the data from slack channel to a file, when we execute the script for fetching the data for one day, it executing perfectly.

But when we execute the script for 2 months data, it gives 10 days data in separate file but getting throwing an error on particular date. It might be possible that the source data on slack is bit different from expected

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Slack SCript\script.py", line 218, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Slack SCript\script.py", line 201, in main
    parse(message['text'])
  File "C:\Users\Slack SCript\script.py", line 114, in parse
    size = float(elements[1])
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

As per the source data we found that some value is `0` maybe the error we got because of this value. is there any way to skip or continue future.

[image]

```
from slackclient import SlackClient
import time
import os
import sys
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

servers = ("fd2a", "ff1a", "hh3b", "kw1a", "kw1b", "lo8a", "os5a", "os5b", "sg2a", "sg2b", 'sy1a', 'va1a', 'va1b')
types = ("", "nfs", "cluster")

currser = "d"
currtype = ""
used = {}
total = {}
available = {}
ts = 0

dir_name = "data"


def savedata(dir_path, filename, data):
    f = open(dir_path + filename, "w")  # opens file with name of "test.txt"
    print(dir_path + filename)
    f.write(data)
    f.close()


def reset_data():
    print("datareset")
    for i in range(0, len(servers)):
        for j in range(0, len(types)):
            used[servers[i] + types[j]] = 0
            total[servers[i] + types[j]] = 0
            available[servers[i] + types[j]] = 0


def write_data(ts):
    datastr = ''
    global used
    global total
    ttotaltotalsum = 0

    for j in range(0, len(types)):

        datastr += types[j] + '\n'
        datastr += "Name\t" + "Region\t" + "total(TB)\t" + "used(TB)\t" + "available(TB)\t" + "Used(%)\n"
        for i in range(0, len(servers)):
            tused = used[servers[i] + types[j]]
            ttotal = total[servers[i] + types[j]]
            ttotaltotalsum += ttotal
            if (ttotal != 0):
                datastr += (
                    servers[i][0:len(servers[i]) - 1] + "\t\t" +
                    servers[i][len(servers[i]) - 1] + "\t\t" +

                    "{:.1f}".format(ttotal / 1024) + " \t\t" +
                    "{:.1f}".format(tused / 1024) + " \t\t" +
                    "{:.1f}".format((ttotal - tused) / 1024) +"\t\t"+
                    "{:.1f}".format(tused / ttotal * 100) + " \t\t" +

                    "  \n")

    print("..")
    if (ttotaltotalsum > 0):
        hour= datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(ts)).hour
        day=  datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(ts)).day

        month=  datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(ts)).month
        year=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(ts)).year


        if hour < 12:
            savedata("data/", "Storage-Update-M-" +
                     str(day) + "-" +
                     str(month) + "-" +
                     str(year) + ".txt", datastr)
        else:
            savedata("data/", "Storage-Update-E-" +
                     str(day) + "-" +
                     str(month) + "-" +
                     str(year) + ".txt", datastr)


def parse(text):
    global currser
    global currtype
    global used
    global total
    global available
    global ts

    content = text.split("\n")

    for line in content:
        line = line[:len(line)]

        if line.__contains__("Netapp Cluster"):
            for server in servers:

                if line.__contains__(server):
                    currser = server
                    for type in types:
                        if line.__contains__(type):
                            currtype = type


                            # print(line)

        if line.__contains__("Total available capacity"):
            # print(line)

            # print ("contains","Total available capacity------")

            elements = line.split(":")
            # print (elements)
            size = float(elements[1])
            # print(size)
            total[currser + currtype] += size
            # print(size,"TOTAL capacity",total)

        elif line.__contains__("size provisioned"):
            # print(line)

            # print("contains", "Total   LUN    size  provisioned------- ")
            elements = line.split(":")
            # print(elements)
            size = float(elements[1])
            # print(size)
            used[currser + currtype] += size
            # print(size, "Used", used)

    # print( currser)
    # print( currtype)
    # print(    used)
    # print(total)
    # print(available)
    return (used, total)


def make_dir(dir_name):
    if not os.path.exists(dir_name):
        os.makedirs(dir_name)


def main():
    slack_token = ""
    channel_name = ''
    time_on_last_message = time.time()
    channel_id = ""
    ts = 0.000
    threshmins = 20
    channels_call = SlackClient(slack_token).api_call("channels.list")
    print(channels_call)

    print(channels_call.keys())

    for channel in channels_call["channels"]:
        if channel["name"] == channel_name:
            channel_id = channel["id"]
            print(channel)

    make_dir(dir_name)
    print(channel_id)
    reset_data()
    time_since_last_update = time.time() - time_on_last_message
    print("Waiting for new data....", time.time() - time_on_last_message)
    if time_since_last_update > threshmins * 60:
        write_data(ts)

        reset_data()

    sc = SlackClient(slack_token)

    date_after_month = datetime.datetime.now() + relativedelta(months=-6)
    date_after_month=date_after_month.timestamp()
    while True:
        breakflag=0
        data = sc.api_call(
            "channels.history",
            channel=channel_id,
            oldest=date_after_month,
            count=1000,
        )

        if (data['ok'] == True):
            messages = data['messages']

            for message in reversed(messages):
                # print(message['ts'])
                if float(message['ts']) > ts:
                    print("difference=", float(message['ts']) - ts)
                    if float(message['ts']) - ts > (threshmins * 60):
                        print("greater diffrrece>reset................")
                        write_data(ts)
                        print(ts)

                        reset_data()

                    time_on_last_message = time.time()

                    ts = float(message['ts'])

                    parse(message['text'])

                if (data["has_more"] == True):
                    print("has more")
                    date_after_month=message['ts']
                else:
                    breakflag=1


        else:
            print("No data returned or error")

        time.sleep(1)  # in Seconds
        if(breakflag==1):
            break


main()
```

Comment: Could you post the `element[1]` value?

Comment: As the error indicates, `elements[1]` is a string that could not be converted to a float. This is all that can be said with the information you have provided. What is the value of `elements[1]` when this occurs?

Comment: I have checked that in some places elements[1] is having value `0`. but such value are on the recent source data also. And we are able to execute the script properly.

Comment: Any suggestion where we can skip this error and continue future.

Comment: providing the actual code you use and the data would help with diagnosis

Comment: I have added the code to the question.

Comment: What data do you need? the source data is on slack. do you need an example data.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, `elements[1]` is empty. And Python cannot convert an empty string to float:

```
>>> float("")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Answer (score 0):

The `elements[1]` element is a string that can't be parsed to a float.  The easiest way would be to attach a debugger and investigate what is being parsed.  Then change your code to parse it better.

The second easiest way would be to binary search for the record that makes it fail and fix your code to parse it better.

The totally absolutely preferred way would be to, when you found what the case was that your code didn't support, you would write a test that proves that that case was added:

```
def test_parse_xyz():
    assert [("blablabla", None)] == parse(["blablabla: -certainly_not_a_float"])
```

These tests can automatically be detected by e.g. [`pytest`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/):

```
$ pytest parser.py
```

Comment: Some value which is in the raw data is having the value `0`. But how can we solve this.

Comment: "0" can perfectly be parsed to float.  You're looking in the wrong corner.  How do you debug this?  Why not create a unit test to reproduce the error?   I see lots of print statements - you probably benefit from investing some time learning to use the debugger and e.g. `pytest`.

Comment: Based on your comment I did some debug and found that there are some values are not available.

Comment: Great news!  It makes sense that 'not available' (or anything equivalent) can't be parsed to float.  Do you know how to create a test for this?